# How to open double curly bracket in idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Maybe this question will be a little silly, but this problem has already got me.

When I press, the `[` button immediately opens the second bracket `[]`,
but when i need `{`, i press `shift+[` and second bracket dont opens, like this `{}`.

The most interesting thing is when I need `(`, combination `shift + 9`, open double `()`.

**How to fix this, strange problem?**

P.s. I know what you will say, "Are you too lazy to press the another key?", no, I'm not too lazy, but I have already developed a habit from MS Visual Studio, where there was no such problem.

Comment: What version of Idea do you have? In Idea 2022.2.1, in settings "Editor->General->Smart Keys" I see option "Insert Paired brackets (), [], {}, <>", which presumably controls everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow following steps

**Step 1**:Go to File

**Step 2**:Search Smart keys

**Step 3**:Select the Insert pair '}' checkbox in the Enter group